# what <T> signifies in <T> void say()

Tags: java, generics

What `<T>` signifies in following code snippet?

```
class Test {    
     <T> void say() {

     }    
}
```

Comment: ... you can delete the whole class AFAIK.

Answer (score 15):

In your example it really does not make sense. But in other cases, if method's return type is void `<T>` still can be used as expected generic parameters type. Consider this

```
public static <T> void test(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    list1.addAll(list2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    test(Arrays.asList(1, 1), Arrays.asList("1", "1"));
}
```

type safety control, javac gives an error, test() expects Lists of the same type.

Another example java.util.Collections.fill

```
public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj) {
    ....
}
```

type safety control again.

Answer (score 8):

It introduces a type placeholder, where `T` maybe pretty much any type. This is typically useful if `T` is part of the signature (either as a parameter or a return type):

```
<T> void say(T myT) {}
say<Object>(myObject);
say<String>(myString);

<U> U foo(U u) { return u; }
String s = foo<String>("");
```

It's rarely useful to introduce a type parameter just for internal use, as the actual `T` is often more interesting for the consumer than the method.

Answer (score 3):

See [this doc about generics in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

But it is useful only if you have parametized types in the argument list.